# Trouble in understanding what should be a subclass or just an instance of a class

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

Hi im having a bit of trouble understanding what should be a subclass or just merely an instance of a class in OWL ontologies

If i use an example of **World Leaders**

You have Presidents, Prime ministers, Chancellors etc

Every one of these is a world leader

So far i have tried to suggest that

All three of these are a subclass of World leader

But if i want to throw in **Head Of State** its where i start to get confused because some world leaders are also heads of state but some arent for example some prime ministers arent head of state

So if i were to throw in head of state would i be correct in assuming that
Head of state would be a subclass of world leader because not every leader is a head of state but every head of state is a leader?

And would President be an instance of head of state or its own subclass? And Also would Prime minister and chancellor be seperated from President like that so Prime minister and Chancellor be subclasses of World leader or actually instances of

Is there a general rule of thumb or guideline of how best to approach this?

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

World Leaders, Presidents, Prime ministers, Chancellors, Heads of State - all of these represent sets which can have many members. Whenever what you are modelling can have multiple members, it is usually best to model using class axioms like subclass rather than individuals.

If you have `A subclass B` and `C subclass D` there is nothing stopping you from having an individual `x` that is a member of both `A` and `D`, except if you have an axiom stating for example stating `A disjoint C` or `B disjoint D`.